# ExactTarget API and .NET email creation

Tags: email, api, marketing-cloud, .net

How can we make email that is being created by the ExactTarget API using .NET pick a layout from ExactTarget to go around the HTML body?

Here is my sample code for the new email:

```
var email = new Email {
  CustomerKey = CorrelationId,
  Name = _name,
  Subject = subject,
  HTMLBody = content,
  CharacterSet = "iso-8859-1",
  EmailType = EmailType.HTML.ToString(),
  CategoryID = EmailCategoryId,
  CategoryIDSpecified = true,
  CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
  CreatedDateSpecified = true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no Template property on an Email so it isn't possible to relate an Email created through the API to a Template. It would however be possible to retrieve an existing Template then use the LayoutHTML property in order to get the HTML which could then be used when creating the Email.

Comment: Can you please send me a .NET sample code to retrieve the template and use it while creating a new email.Can I use the layout and set the content when creating the email?.

Comment: Please share what code you are currently trying for this.

Comment: I dont see LayoutHTML property for Email object.How do we set the Layout here.var email = new Email{                 CustomerKey = CorrelationId,
                      Name = _name,
                      Subject = subject,
                      HTMLBody = content,
                      CharacterSet = "iso-8859-1",
                      EmailType = EmailType.HTML.ToString(),
                      CategoryID = EmailCategoryId,
                      CategoryIDSpecified = true,
                      CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                      CreatedDateSpecified = true};

Comment: On the Email Object, it would be HTMLBody

Comment: There does not exist LayoutHTML property on Email object for version 0.9.

Comment: Look for HTMLBody instead of LayoutHTML